# Getting error to failed to look up JNDI DataSource in WebLogic

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource, spring-jdbc, weblogic12c

I'm using WebLogic 12.2.1.4, I have already created the datasource with the name "jdbc/TESTDataSource but still getting the below error. Is there are any additional steps that I'm missing here. Please help.

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/TESTDataSource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/jdbc/TESTDataSource in /app/webapp/TEST.war/1431676420.; remaining name 'comp/env/jdbc/TESTDataSource'

Comment: Did you check that you datasource is correctly deployed in your server ? Check the JNDI tree in the admin console to see if the datasource is present or not.